# How to download CSV file and return to the page using Python and Django

Tags: python, django, csv

I am generating the CSV file and downloading it but after download it need to return to the other page using Python but its not happening like this.

My code is below:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        param = request.POST.get('param')
        report = Reactor.objects.all()
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=status.csv'
        writer = csv.writer(response)
        writer.writerow(['Name', 'Status', 'Date'])
        for rec in report:
            if rec.status == 1:
                status = 'Start'
            if rec.status == 0:
                status = 'Stop'
            if rec.status == 2:
                status = 'Suspend'
            writer.writerow([rec.rname, status, rec.date])
        return response
        u = urllib.URLopener()
        f = u.open(param)
        open("down.txt","w").write(f.read())
        pers = User.objects.get(pk=request.session['id'])
        root = []
        user_name = pers.uname
        count = 1
        root.append(
            {'username': user_name,
             'count': count
             })
    return render(request, 'plant/home.html',
                  {'user': root, 'count': 1})
```

Here actually user input is one `URL e.g
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopep8` like this. Here my requirement is first all required data will fetch from database and write inside one CSV file and download it. secondly the user provided URL content will be written on a text file and download it finally the required page will be redirected. In my case after downloading the CSV file only the page is remaining same means not redirecting.

Comment: you can't redirect and send a file using the same response. You will need to do it in two steps, for example do the redirect and then download the csv file in the redirected page through javascript.

Comment: @alfonso.kim : Can you share your coding accordingly ?